# How do I trim the unused space in Flexbox container?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that my `.Header-item` is too wide.
[image]
I want to trim out the unused space.

Attaching the HTML code.

```html
<body class="d-flex">
    <div id="root" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="Header color-bg-subtle color-shadow-medium">
            <div class="Header-item">
                <a class="Header-link" href="/">
                    <img src="/vtitbid.tech-logo-no-padding.png" style="width: 20%;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Header-item f4">
                <a class="Header-link color-fg-default" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Header-item mr-0 ml-auto">
                <button class="btn-mktg btn btn-primary" type="button">Стать участником</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS of `.Header-item`:

```css
.Header-item {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 16px;
    align-self: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

CSS of `.Header`:

```css
.Header {
    z-index: 32;
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: var(--color-header-text);
    background-color: var(--color-header-bg);
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: [take a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

Comment: Have you tried `max-width`?

Comment: Show a [reprex], at least the CSS for `.Header` as that element controls the distribution of the flex child elements...

Comment: Remove the `style="width: 20%;` from `<img>` and add CSS for it giving it a `width` in `px` or `rem/em`. Right now it uses up 20% of the total width of the header.

Comment: This solved the issue! Can you please provide an answer with a full explanation? I'll accept it.